# Google Maps V3 creating polygon from county name in XML data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Well I have run into a bit of a small problem and I am not sure how to approach this. I have this test map.

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap_poly.html

Which creates polygons based on data from this XML file.

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/warnings.xml

It displays weather alerts/watches/warnings etc on the map from the data which makes the polygon that shows what area the alert is in and I have an array in another file that assigns the color. All that works great.

Here is my problem. The XML feed doesn't always display alerts with polygon cords that can be split to create latlng object to create the polygons, I will only get county names half the time so there may be alerts in the feed but they will never get displayed if there is no polygon cords. If you look at the feed for cap:polygon you'll see not all of them have it. Right above it though is areaDesc which is the county name. So is there an easy way to create a polygon base on the county name from that data and how?

I have been searching the web with no results. I did read about fusion tables but will that work and can I use that to draw the polygons based on the data from the feed then have fusion tables draw it out? I don't know, I am doing stuff with Google Maps I have never done before so I am out of my element and could use some guidance and assistance. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly welcomed so I can put this project to sleep.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FusionTables to display a FusionTablesLayer with specific counties on it, and style those polygons dynamically (with up to 5 style rules).

[FusionTable containing US counties](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw#map%3aid=17)

[Selected counties](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col4+from+0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw+where+col3+contains+ignoring+case+%27TX-H%27&h=false&lat=31.516673686978027&lng=-98.13374775&z=5&t=1&l=col4&y=3&tmplt=3)

[Example that displays the counties (using a FusionTablesLayer) on the map](http://www.geocodezip.com/mesquiteweather_net_PolygonInfoWindowsB.html)

[Proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mesquiteweather_net_PolygonInfoWindowsE_GViz.html?filename=../mesquiteweather_net_nat_warnings.xml), not sure this will be usable with this many counties.

[Probably OK with a small number of counties (your original example)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mesquiteweather_net_PolygonInfoWindowsE_GViz.html?filename=../mesquiteweather_net_warnings_test.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I came across all that in my research. I have it running on this test map... http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap.html What I am curious about is can I use it to only display counties from my XML feed as needed as well as polygons as need from that feed? I haven't been able to find information pertaining to that.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can see some examples of how to use this from dynamic content from an XML? From there I should be able to integrate it into my existing code but I can't find anything related to using Fusion Tables with XML/KML data.

Comment: You have to write code to do that.  You need to create a FusionTableLayer with a query that will display the polygons that you want.  It is doable, but I don't know of a tutorial that will explain it for you.

Comment: That is where I am stuck. I have been looking for 24hrs straight trying to find something that shows how to display the polygons from XML file using Fusion tables. I have no clue where to even start. I have the fusion layer showing on a test map but, I only need to show certain counties from the XML file and get it's style from the polygon style that is already present. Sounds easy enough but I can't find any informaiton. Just stuff on how to set up a table and layer. That part i've done...LOL

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap.html

that is the map I am testing on.

Comment: See the example added to my answer that parses the FIPS6 code out of the XML and displays those counties on the map.

Comment: Ok let me take a look and play around with that for a while. The county information is under <cap:areaDesc>. You have been a HUGE help thank you. Least I have some direction now.

Comment: There is still a bunch of work to do.  You probably want to query the FusionTable for the coordinates of the county polygons rather than using a FusionTablesLayer to display it.  But one step at a time...

Comment: would you mind in your demo map trying this xml file so I can see if you get the same output as I am getting. This is the live xml file where the other is a test. It outputs the numbers below the map but not on it. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/nat_warnings.xml

Comment: There are too many counties that need to be displayed on the FusionTablesLayer in that feed, the IN construct in FusionTables is limited by the URL length restriction. http://www.geocodezip.com/mesquiteweather_net_PolygonInfoWindowsB.html?filename=mesquiteweather_net_nat_warnings.xml

Comment: I assume you are referring to this line correct? var queryStr = "'GEO_ID2' IN('" + FTcountyFIPS.join("','")+"')"; Is this something that can be changed or is this a limitation of the Fusion Tables? If I can get all the counties to display in a test map. I would think I could display less than all when needed.

Comment: See the "proof of concept" I added to my answer.  Not sure you can use this approach, it has serious performance issues with that many counties, particularly in IE.

Comment: Holy crap man! I didn't know it would take that much work! Thanks you so much, you didn't have to do all that. I do see the performance issues in IE you're referring to. I guess that is just the nature of the beast or is there something I can do to make that a bit faster? If it comes down to it I can throw an IE exception in there and just show the static gif image from NWS instead for users on IE kind of like the SWFObect works with a disclaimer message. It works really well on the state and local level http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap.html

Comment: I think I may have found where the performance issue is. If you look at this screenshot http://www.mesquiteweather.net/screenshots/warnings_screenshots.png IE is drawing multiple polygons if that county has more than one alert where Firefox isn't with the exception of the Amber Alert below the dark blue Firefox draws it under the warning. So it should draw it by severity I.E. Statement/Advisory/Watch/Warning. So I am looking into that and separating layers between County/Storm/Radar and putting them on buttons. Would that help? How do I remove the query output below the map safely?

Comment: Thank you for ALL your help. Everything is running perfectly. How do I remove the query output from displaying on the page with the map safely?

Comment: You mean this line? `document.getElementById("FTquery2").innerHTML = FT_Query2;`

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I was playing around with those lines but I was removing to much. Should have known it was something simple. Thank you so much for all your help I have learned so much from you which is allowing me to apply so much to my other maps. Things are starting to make a lot more sense to how Google Maps are structured and work. I have noticed the performance is greatly better when there isn't a lot of alerts. I.E. http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxsvr.php which only has like 3-4 around Houston but the color makes it hard to see. Ignore the table at the bottom. Thank you again!